# SQL Return all combinations from multiple rows/columns

Tags: sql, combinations, probability

I have tables with prob of an event happening (sum is not equal to 1) like :

```
Outcome 1 - 0.1  Outcome 2 - 0.2  Outcome 3 - 0.4  Outcome 4 - 0.6
```

I want all the possible number of picks from this - like:

```
P1 - 
0.1*(1-0.2)*(1-0.4)*(1-0.6) + 0.2*(1-0.1)*(1-0.4)*(1-0.6) + 0.4*(1-0.2)*(1-0.1)*(1-0.6) + 0.6*(1-0.2)*(1-0.4)*(1-0.1)

P2 - 
0.1*(0.2)*(1-0.4)*(1-0.6) + 0.2*(1-0.1)*(0.4)*(1-0.6) + 0.4*(1-0.2)*(1-0.1)*(0.6) + 0.6*(1-0.2)*(1-0.4)*(0.1) + 0.1*(1-0.2)*(0.4)*(1-0.6) + 0.6*(0.2)*(1-0.4)*(1-0.1)

P3 - 
0.1*0.2*0.4*(1-0.6) + 0.6*0.2*0.4*(1-0.1) + 0.1*0.6*0.4*(1-0.2) + 0.1*0.2*0.6*(1-0.4)

P4 -
0.1*0.2*0.4*0.6
```

Outcome 1,2,3,4 & P1,2,3,4 are columns

Comment: I don't get the question.

You mean that the equations are columns or that you have inserted the data {0.1, 0.2, 0.4 & 0,6) and you want the query to use those inserted params and insert calculated results from above equations into the table?

Comment: What does this have to with SQL?  What do your tables look like?  What are the columns and the rows?  If you are using SQL, what database?  Please provide a tag.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
DROP TABLE if exists #temp;
SELECT

   0.1 as Outcome1,
   0.2 as Outcome2,
   0.3 as Outcome3,
   0.4 as Outcome4
INTO #temp;

SELECT 
   Outcome1 * (1-Outcome2) * (1-Outcome3) * (1-Outcome4) as P1,
   Outcome2 * Outcome1 * (1-Outcome3) * (1-Outcome4) as P2,
   Outcome3 * Outcome1 * Outcome2 * (1-Outcome4) as P3,
   Outcome4 * Outcome1 * Outcome2 * Outcome3 as P4
FROM #temp T1
```

output:

```
P1             P2              P3                P4
-------------- --------------- ----------------- ------------------
0.0336         0.0084          0.0036            0.0024
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dff8f4a3b40ef4ba9ecc28946a45c728)

EDIT: Update because i did not have the definitions correct:

```
SELECT
   0.1 as Outcome1,
   0.2 as Outcome2,
   0.4 as Outcome3,
   0.6 as Outcome4
INTO #temp;

SELECT 
   Outcome1*(1-Outcome2)*(1-Outcome3)*(1-Outcome4) + 
   Outcome2*(1-Outcome1)*(1-Outcome3)*(1-Outcome4) + 
   Outcome3*(1-Outcome2)*(1-Outcome1)*(1-Outcome4) + 
   Outcome4*(1-Outcome2)*(1-Outcome3)*(1-Outcome1)  as P1,
   Outcome1*(Outcome2)*(1-Outcome3)*(1-Outcome4) + 
   Outcome2*(1-Outcome1)*(Outcome3)*(1-Outcome4) + 
   Outcome3*(1-Outcome2)*(1-Outcome1)*(Outcome4) + 
   Outcome4*(1-Outcome2)*(1-Outcome3)*(Outcome1) + 
   Outcome1*(1-Outcome2)*(Outcome3)*(1-Outcome4) + 
   Outcome4*(Outcome2)*(1-Outcome3)*(1-Outcome1) as P2,
   Outcome1*Outcome2*Outcome3*(1-Outcome4) + 
   Outcome4*Outcome2*Outcome3*(1-Outcome1) + 
   Outcome1*Outcome4*Outcome3*(1-Outcome2) + 
   Outcome1*Outcome2*Outcome4*(1-Outcome3) as P3,
   Outcome1 * Outcome2 * Outcome3 * Outcome4 as P4
FROM #temp T1
```

output:

```
P1      P2      P3      P4
0.4368  0.3128  0.0728  0.0048
```

Updated [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a82b898f0ec0babecd57343128a57a30)

Comment: no, P1 is [Outcome1 * (1-Outcome2) * (1-Outcome3) * (1-Outcome4)] + [Outcome2* (1-Outcome1) * (1-Outcome3) * (1-Outcome4)] + [Outcome3 * (1-Outcome2) * (1-Outcome1) * (1-Outcome4)] + [Outcome14* (1-Outcome2) * (1-Outcome3) * (1-Outcome1)]. and i don't want to hardcode this, let me know if there is solution other than that

Comment: There is no (built-in) function to do that kind of think, so you will have to hard code it. (And sorry, i missed parts of the complex addition, but the explanation of what should happen was missing.... )

Comment: Updated the formula's, i hope I did not make a typing error.